# How do I use conditional formatting for an increasing value in a column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I know it's possible for this, but I don't have the knowledge to figure out what to do.  I have an excel spreadsheet that i want the cells to gradually change colours as the hours increase.

Starting at green for 1700 hours, amber at 1904, red at 1905 until it gets to 2000, from 2001 it changes back to green.  I need this to be ongoing every 300 hours.  I've listed below the column so you can see an example of the entries.  Some days, no hours are entered.

I have tried copying a conditional formatting formula which I was given by another user which worked fine starting from zero.

Formula is here:

[image]

```
Green'=MOD(N5,300)=0'
Orange ="MOD(N4,300)=204'
Red=OR(MOD(N5,300)>205,MOD(N5,300)=1)
```

[image]

Comment: i'm still lost sorry. so the formula is working, then what's your problem?

Comment: The formula is working on a different worksheet where the first cell starts at 0 and increases every 500. This cell starts at 1700 and I want it to change every 300. It's missing out.  The amber colour when I apply it

Comment: So every 300 hours the color will shift form green to red and vise versa?

Comment: Yes, the formatting doesn't seem to be working if you look at my example

Comment: @l42, i've figured out my formula error, orange needed to be >108, red >204.  The problem I have now is that 1700 is where the count needs to start from.  Going on the formula I have, 1700 will be red, then green again at 1800.  I need the count to start from 1700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**Edit1:**

```
=AND(MOD($N5-1700,300)<108,$N5<>"") '~~> GREEN
=MOD($N5-1700,300)>204 '~~> RED
=AND(MOD($N5-1700,300)>=108,MOD($N5-1700,300)<=204 '~~> ORANGE
```

This is the easiest i can come up with.
column N should contain numbers starting from 1700 only.

Comment: Thanks, that's working, just one more question to be a pain, the cells that don't have anything entered turn green, is it possible to have these kept blank?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure if this should be a new question. One of my pumps has 3 engines that has different hours each day. Is it possible to do the same kind of conditional formatting for them? EG O1 Jan Pump 1 8847 hours, pump 2 7253, pump 3 8270.  03 Jan Pump 1 8891, Pump 2 7279, Pump 3 8314.  I've put an example in my original question

Comment: yes, but the way your data is structured, you'll have to make 3 different formatting for each engine. And then you'll have to copy the formatting of engine 1 to 1, 2 to 2  and 3 to 3. Be careful with copy-pasting conditional formatting though. be sure to check where it is applied. else, you will not get the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean by make 3 different formatting for each engine.  In the applied to, do i need to select every cell for engine 1?

Comment: That's the best way for the formatting not to overlap. If however, you have the same conditions for each engine, then there's no need to. I'm just thinking that maybe your engines have different intervals.

Comment: they all need to get serviced at 500 hours, its just the starting hours are different and sometimes they aren't running so that makes the hours different for each engine.  I take it there is no easy way to select each engine 1 as there is 1100 rows to go through